# How can I search for Comments made to Posts I have made in Facebook Groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I find that comments to posts I have made (on my wall or to FB Groups) get buried among all the Likes and other notifications.
While I'm as narcissistic as the next person, I'd rather ignore the Likes.

Is there a way to view ONLY comments made to my posts?
Or perhaps a Notification Setting?
(I looked and can't see that level of granulatiry. Just "Activity Involves You" (but that could be a Like of my Post or a Comment)

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in your account.
2. Go to your Profile.
3. There you can see an "View Activity Log" click on that.[image]
4. There you can see your comments, likes, new added friends, pages liked, updated profile.
5. There you can delete, hide your comments.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this natively.

The closest will be

"Posts in `<Group>` by me commented on by people in `<Group>`"

switch `<Group>` for group name

`https://www.facebook.com/search/<group-id>/members/stories-commented/<group-id>/stories-in/me/stories-by/intersect`

For groups another way will be to just search for your name when using the search feature in the group.

Comment: Doesn't work currently. (Error: This Content Isn't Available Right Now
When this happens, it's usually because the owner only shared it with a small group of people, changed who can see it or it's been deleted.)